# Google Analytics API and custom variables?

Tags: api, google-analytics, custom-fields

We've got a web directory and we'd like to use google's API to display demographic numbers to our clients for pages that their directory listing is shown for. We've reviewed GA's analytics documentation and can create graphs, but no way that we can see to grab metrics (like percentage of mobile users vs desktop) for ONLY pages where those custom variables were present.

For instance, on the directory search page, we want to be able to tell customer X that their business showed up 100 times, that 78% of them were mobile users, and that a breakdown of cities. How can I do this using GA's API code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any future googlers, this is not currently possible through the API.